# OpenLayers 'zoom to extent' issue on swipe tool

Tags: javascript, openlayers, swipe

I am working with OpenLayers version 3.16 in which I have added few layers and comparing those using swipe tool OL3-ext. Layers are coming from GeoServer.

While zooming to extent on selected layers my OpenLayers 3 is crashing. Please check attached screenshots as following.

Tried flowing to resolve error:-

1.In single map (on one layer) zoom to extent working fine.

2.Updated my layers order.

3.Checking related questions in GIS.SE

Screenshots:-

1.Before comparing two different layers using swipe tool selected layer highlighted in red color.

[image]

2.After zoom to selection OpenLayers crashes (highlighted in red color)

[image]

Comment: Is there an error message from OpenLayers? Additionally, can you use your browser's developer tools to confirm that all tiles have 1) finished loading and 2) don't have an error message returned instead of an image?